# Filtering Dual Threshold Image Using the Seed Point Entered

Tags: python, opencv

I have marked a seed point inside an polygon to dual threshold that polygon. I want to remove the rest of the connected Components after the thresholding image depends on the seed point i have marked. I have the coordinates of the seed point according to the cropped image. I want to remove the rest of the unwanted labeled components to set as zero and get only the necessary image segment to show. Imagine that the center coordinate as(x=37,y=40).

Extracted Image with the seed point [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYbub.png)

Dual threshold image for the extracted image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mPHN.png)

Following is the code is upto the getting connected components from the extracted image.

```
def dual_threshold_method(crop_img):
mean, meanStd = cv2.meanStdDev(crop_img)
w = 2.0
lower_Threshold = mean - (w * meanStd) + 90
upper_Threshold = mean + (w * meanStd) + 90
ret1, img1 = cv2.threshold(crop_img, int(lower_Threshold), 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret2, img2 = cv2.threshold(crop_img, int(upper_Threshold), 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dual_threshold_img = img1 - img2
retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(dual_threshold_img)
cv2.imshow('Dual_Threshold_Image', dual_threshold_img)
return labels, retval
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UbXkYyCiMqVRXhn_KuSaKRHDUtQWhdnl?usp=sharing

Above link contains the dual threshold image and the seed point marked image

Expected Result will be same as the below images

https://drive.google.com/open?id=14zaQWz9C3qRNN-niM4LI1-iCenk7QIMN

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by using the center coordinate pixel intensity to filter and added dilate and erosion.

```
pixel_value = labels[cropped_image_center_coordinates[0][0],cropped_image_center_coordinates[0][1]]
mask = np.array(labels, dtype=np.uint8)
mask[labels == pixel_value] = 255
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('component', erosion)enter code here
```